# Programmatically create ListView with custom style - Why is android:layout_marginXY not recognized?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-styles

I am trying to create a new ListView programmatically and to apply a custom style to is:

```
// Somewhere within a Fragment...
ListView myListView = new ListView(getActivity(), null, R.attr.myListViewStyle);
someContainerView.addView(myListView);

// In attrs.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="AppTheme">
        <attr name="myListViewStyle" format="reference"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>

// in styles.xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="myListViewStyle">@style/ListViewStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="BookingsSectionListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <!-- Setting the Padding DOES work... -->
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">50dp</item>

    <!-- ...while setting the Margin has NO effect -->
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">50dp</item>  
</style>
```

While the creation of the ListView is no problem the custom style is not applied correctly. The `android:layout_marginXY` attributes are not recognized and thus the ListView is not placed correctly. If I use `android:paddingX` instead everything works fine. **Why is that?**

If I don't create the the ListView programmatically but directly in XML and apply the style to it the `android:layout_marginXY` attributes works without any problem.

**What is the difference between creating the ListView and applying the style in XML or Java?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't think of `layout_*` attributes as a part of child's style (`ListView` in this case).
 `layout_*` attributes are in context of the parent to which the child is added. They tell the parent where to position and how to layout a child (child doesn't have this logic).

In this line:

```
ListView myListView = new ListView(getActivity(), null, R.attr.myListViewStyle);
```

all attributes are passed to the `ListView` and the style will be applied to the `ListView` itself. It doesn't have any parent - it's just newly created object not attached to view hierarchy yet.

```
someContainerView.addView(myListView);
```

This is a line where `LayputParams` are assigned to child. You are not specifying any `LayoutParams` (there are different version on this method), so the default one will be used.

Comment: Thank you very much! That makes things much clearer!